# Merge [mortar], [pestle], and [mortar-pestle]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

These three tags are pretty blatantly about the same piece of equipment:

- [mortar](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortar)
- [pestle](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pestle)
- [mortar-pestle](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortar-pestle)

I propose them to be merged. I prefer [mortar-pestle](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortar-pestle) to be the parent tag as it minimises confusion when auto-replaced for new users.

Comment: Anyone have preferences which tag wins out?

Comment: @Cascabel: See my edit …

Comment: Why not "mortar-and-pestle" ? You have plenty of characters.

Comment: mortar-and-pestle, pestle-and-mortar, mortar-with-pestle, pestle-in-mortar, mortar-but-i-cant-find-the-pestle, mortal-pestilence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done, merged all into [mortar-and-pestle](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortar-and-pestle) and created syns.